# Upcoming Birthdays SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have the birthdays stored liked this: 277081200. Is there a way to ORDER the employees by day and month of their Birthdays? I managed to show their birthdays but in no Order.
I guess that before showing them i have to Order them somehow.

```
$results=mysql_query("SELECT name,surname,dob FROM employees_table WHERE active LIKE 'TRUE' ORDER BY dob",$con);
```

Comment: Parse your storage format for us. what does 277081200 mean?

Comment: it's the time in seconds since the Epoch on Linux

Comment: Why are you storing dates like that, rather than something... well, logical?  Like a `Date` or even `DateTime`.

Comment: It was not my decision. I didn't do that. But now i have to do something.

Comment: I'm not sure the exact syntax in MySQL, but you'll need to convert the value into a `Date` datatype in your query, and order by the `DatePart` of that converted field.

Comment: The firm doesn't want older employees ...

Comment: So no one is older than 43?

Answer (score 0):

The order by clause can be as such for the exact ordering you're looking for:

```
ORDER BY YEAR(NOW()) + CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('1970-01-01', INTERVAL -800000 SECOND),'%m%d') > DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m%d') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD('1970-01-01', INTERVAL -800000 SECOND),'%m%d')
```

This puts next January's dob's after this December's dob's, and will properly put birthdays passed this year into next year's list. Hope this helps.

Comment: It is working but some dates are represented with 'minus'in front of the number. <http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm> for example: 07/19/1965. And these are left behind.

Comment: See my edit. You'll want to avoid FROM_UNIXTIME(), and go with DATE_ADD() instead. The syntax is in the edit.

Comment: I changed the date format, not it's yyyy-mm-dd. I am selecting the days and months but I don't know how to combine the sql string to put them in order, for example: 07-20 would be in front of 08-05. `$results=mysql_query("SELECT name,surname,dob, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dob)AS birthmonth, EXTRACT(DAY FROM dob) AS birthday FROM employees WHERE active LIKE 'TRUE' ORDER BY birthmonth AND birthday ASC; ",$con);`

Comment: Right, to put the months in reverse order, simply add `DESC` to the last `ORDER BY` term.